# bitcoin full node huge upload bandwidth

Tags: bandwidth

Have been running a full node for a couple of months now, using bitcoin core 25.0
Last time I was running a node was many years ago, so I a bit outdated...

I am wondering if upload stats are not a bit huge.

**I am around 90 GB uploaded per day!**

I have a good connection (arond 500 Mbps Upload), not complaining, still this means a lot of usage of it, disk, and so on.
I am wondering where all the traffic comes from , probably not from transactions, but mostly from new nodes downloading big chunks of the full blockchain from me?

Do you have similar stats on full nodes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bitcoin Core uploads much more than it downloads](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/107151/bitcoin-core-uploads-much-more-than-it-downloads)

Comment: Partly...indeed my node is correctly listening and joinable.  Still it seems to me 90 GB a day is huge, considering number of daily blocks....   I also heard about erlay protocol which should have partly solved the traffic generated by flooding, but I am not sure if it's already implemented in bt-core.

Comment: If you're seeing that much traffic, it is very likely almost entirely due to people downloading historical blocks from you. Bitcoin Core has a feature to limit how much you're willing to upload per day, if this is an issue.